# How to re-flag a semi-removed conversation

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags

I flagged all comments of [@Tim Lloyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189516/tim-lloyd)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7128424/4519059) as those were not longer needed altogether as you can see it's old version [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128399/c-sharp-how-many-days-left-in-year-from-datetime-now); But for more readability here:

```
#1- You need a cast: TotalDays returns a double. – Jon Skeet Aug 19 '11 at 23:32    
#2- @Jon There is a cast? – Tim Lloyd Aug 19 '11 at 23:33
#3- Doh - I'm clearly too tired. Sorry! – Jon Skeet Aug 19 '11 at 23:36
#4- @Jon I hear you - time to go to bed :) – Tim Lloyd Aug 19 '11 at 23:36
```

Instead of first one(#1) all other comments removed as my flag was helpful, but for first one it declined. As you see in conversation the first comment is also no longer needed, but I can't flag it again or flag it in another way, I think it should also remove as it was a wrong comment described by followed comments, But now it's make many bad feelings to a user who see that single comment from [@Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).
I'm feeling bad also, as I think I make Tim's answer lower worth!

What should I do know?
Should I write a comment for Jon to remove his comment?
Or is there anyway to undo my flags?

Answer (score 2):

Even though [you are no longer allowed to flag a comment multiple times for the same reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300356), you can still use the custom/other reason to flag the comment. This forces you to *explain* what's wrong with the comment and why you want it removed, which is what you should be doing anyway if your first flag was declined.

An alternative to that would be to flag the associated *post* with a custom reason and explain why the comment(s) need to be deleted. Supposedly opinions vary among the moderator team, but I personally prefer that you do this if an entire comment "thread" is obsolete and should be removed as a unit (as opposed to flagging each one individually).

---

I already deleted that one, though, while you were composing this Meta question, so no reason to flag it now. I was processing some of your comment flags on *other* answers to that same question, and when I do that, I usually scroll through and look at comments on other answers to see if those need to be cleaned up, too. In this case, it pretty clearly needed to be removed.

I don't know why the moderator who originally processed the comment flags there declined the first one. Maybe they weren't looking at the comment thread in context and didn't see that it was irrelevant. Maybe they were afraid that you were abusing "no longer needed" as a way to get comments removed that you disagree with or think are technically incorrect. Maybe it was just a misclick.

Comment: I think as a moderator when I see that single comment - or that semi-removed comments- I'll decline it as you noted it that you always see comments thread, but now that comment thread is halfed and don't make a correct sense ;).

Comment: Alternative way: you meant that I flag whole of a post then describe it to moderators to delete all or some comments of that post?

Comment: Yes, @shA.t. The "flag" link under the post, click "in need of moderator intervention", and then ask to have the comments removed (and explain why).

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note, one of the other moderators accidentally declined a number of your flags that they should have marked "helpful", so you are currently banned from flagging. That's a mistake, and we are working on correcting it. Sorry for the confusion! @shA.t

Comment: Oh! thanks for clarifing me ;).

Comment: Done. I missed that one, @shA.t. Why are you bothering to edit them if you're flagging them for removal?

Comment: I usually edit posts as a habit ;).